# Broken iPhone, no back-up - How can I access my contacts

Tags: iphone, icloud, contacts

So my phone's been in the wars. The screen died on me this morning, it struggles to charge unless I find the sweet-spot, fiddle with the wire and keep it in that exact position.

I haven't backed up the contacts on icloud or itunes (foolishly assuming it did that automatically).

I've been to EE and they don't save the contacts on the nano sim either...

Is there any way of extracting my contacts from the phone? I use it for work and not having those numbers, is not an option for me!

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: Possible low tech solution: Connect the phone to your computer/power outlet, fiddle with the wire, and hold it while a friend helps copy your contacts either by backing up to iCloud/computer or by checking "Contacts" in your iCloud settings on your phone.

Comment: Get the screen fixed. Buy a new cable, or at least clean the electrical contacts in the lightning connector. No backup means just that, no backup.    If the screen doesn't work at all, I'm not sure how you'd be able to connect it to a computer to backup now, as you wouldn't be able to authorise it.